# my code runs, but did not happen anything (Tkinter, Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

can someone tell me, what's wrong with my script ._.
it's run but nothing happend.
my purpose is create a new window if i click my "input button" on "mainWindow".
and my mainWindow did't show anything :(
can someone tell me the clue for fix this problem ?
thank you for your time :)

```
from tkinter import*

master = Tk()

# create frame menu
def mainWindow(self, master):
    menuFrame = Frame(master)

    inputButton = Button(menuFrame, text="Input Data", command=windowInput)
    showButton = Button(menuFrame, text="Show Data")
    deleteButton = Button(menuFrame, text="Delete Data")

    menuFrame.pack(fill=BOTH)
    inputButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
    showButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
    deleteButton.grid(row=0, column=1)


    # create new window
def windowInput():
    window_input = Toplevel(master)
    window_input.wm_title("Input")
    inputFrame = Frame(master)

    kodeLabel = Label(inputFrame, text="Book Kode")
    nameLabel = Label(inputFrame, text="Book Name")
    priceLabel = Label(inputFrame, text="Book Price")
    kodeEntry = Entry(inputFrame)
    nameEntry = Entry(inputFrame)
    priceEntry = Entry(inputFrame)
    submitButton = Button(inputFrame, text="Submit", command=NONE)
    backButton = Button(inputFrame, text="Back", command=NONE)

    inputFrame.pack()
    kodeLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
    nameLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
    priceLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
    kodeEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    nameEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    priceEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
    submitButton.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
    backButton.grid(row=3, column=2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you  don't pass anything in `def mainWindow(self, master):` like `def mainWindow():` and if you change the if statement from

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    master.mainloop()
```

to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainWindow()
    windowInput()
    master.mainloop()
```

it should work

Comment: thanks bro, my script is work now. but i only put mainWindow() on if main blablabla.
if i use windowInput(), when i start my script i got 2 window at the same time hehehe
thanks dude, very helpfull

Comment: I'm happy that your code works ;) If you want you can check my answer as the answer who solved your problem!